# How do I align the contents inside my container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I have a few buttons that I've added inside this rounded container. I want to align alll go these in the middle. Originally when I added them they were perfectly aligned but when I changed the size of the text below the buttons the alignment got changed as well. Here is the code:

```
  Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 290.0, left: 8, right: 8),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)),
                    ),
                    height: 110,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 110.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 198.0, left: 0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 50,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      const Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                      const Color(0xFFFE524B)
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                                child: Icon(Entypo.login,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text('Sign In', style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                fontFamily: "Netflix",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 17)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 198.0, left: 25),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 50,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      const Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                      const Color(0xFFFE524B)
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 2.0, top: 1),
                                  child: Container(
                                      child: Icon(Entypo.credit,
                                          color: Colors.white)),
                                )),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text('Payments', style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                fontFamily: "Netflix",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 17)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 198.0, left: 15),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 50,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      const Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                      const Color(0xFFFE524B)
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                      child: Icon(Entypo.log_out,
                                          color: Colors.white)),
                                )),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text('Sign Out', style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                fontFamily: "Netflix",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 17)),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 198.0, left: 20),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 50,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      const Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                      const Color(0xFFFE524B)
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                      child: Icon(Entypo.info,
                                          color: Colors.white)),
                                )),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text('About Us', style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
                                fontFamily: "Netflix",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 17)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

This is what the alignment looks like: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the buttons in a row. And then, you can set MainAxisAlignment property to center.

Comment: when im doing that my containers get joined to each other. How do I create an even spacing between them while still keeping them aligned?

Comment: For spacing, you can use SizedBox between the widgets and give it the required width. So, you have to put your buttons in a row and put SizedBox() between them.

Answer (score 0):

Put the buttons in a row. And then, you can set MainAxisAlignment property to center.

Comment: when im doing that my containers get joined to each other. How do I create an even spacing between them while still keeping them aligned?